# pgfplotstable show subset of rows?

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv

I'm visualizing a csv with pgfplotstable as following:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    col sep = comma,
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    columns={{packo id},{N}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]
{csv/comparison.csv}
```

However, I would like to show only a subset of the rows in the file. For instance, row 20 to 100. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can have a look at `skip between rows` key and apply twice

Comment: @percusse an answer, sir?

Comment: I was able to do it with two lines: "skip rows between index={0}{20}, "skip rows between index={100}{1000}". If you add that as an answer I can accept it if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys `skip between rows` can be applied more than once. For frequent intervals it is tedious to write it but can be used to select different row groups.

Here as OP mentioned this is utilized as

```
skip rows between index={0}{20},
skip rows between index={100}{1000}
```

will skip the initial 20 and the interval `[100,1000]` inclusive.